# How does the "is" keyword work?

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services

More specifically, why does this work:

```
foreach (ChangeSetEntry changeRow in changeSet.ChangeSetEntries)
    if (changeRow is RouteStage)
    { ... }
```

but this not?

```
ChangeSetEntry changeRow = changeSet.ChangeSetEntries[0];
if (changeRow is RouteStage)
{ ... }
```

In the latter case, I get a compiler warning saying:

> The given expression is never of the provided type.

I can understand that, as `changeRow` is a `ChangeSetEntry` not a `RouteStage`, so why does it work inside the `foreach` block?

This is in my override of the `Submit` method in an RIA Services DomainService. `RouteStage` is an entity I have defined to be returned by the `DomainService`.

Comment: It might be giving you a warning because `changeSet.ChangeSetEntries[0]` might an argument out of range exception, whereas the `foreach` will simply not execute if there are no objects it the collection, so the `is` line will never get called.

Comment: The answer is in the definition of the `ChangeSetEntries` property

Comment: Ah you *sure* the two code blocks are referring to the same types? Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I assume the warning is on the `if` line, by the way?

Comment: I'd expect both snippets to work. I seem to remember implementing it in several projects. I usually use it for shorthand when upcasting (instead of convert, catch exception if thrown, etc)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm `guessing` that the `ChangeSetEntries` collection might be of type `IEnumerable`, instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. What do you think?

Comment: @Tim: No, you'd still get the same warning. I suspect this is a matter of some type existing in two different namespaces.

Comment: Does it have to do with the implementation of IEnumerable? You can also create a foreach with at the left side a type that can't be in the list.

Comment: @HighCore: That wouldn't affect the `is` check. The type of `changeRow` is the same in each case.

Comment: @JonSkeet but doing `foreach` over an `IEnumerable` (non-generic one) will return `object`, therefore the compiler has no way to know that will "never be of the provided type"

Comment: It does not work, it just doesn't give you a warning, most likely because it would only be processed at run time.

Comment: I can't repeat this problem with VS2013, the warning is there in both cases with all typed collection types I could think of trying.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I tested with the exact same case you described (override of Submit in a RIA domain service class). Both are producing the same warning.

Comment: @HighCore: The compiler does have a way to know that, because we declare the type of the variable in the `foreach` loop. So the variable is strongly typed.

Comment: @HighCore All of that is irrelivant; the result of the `IEnumerable` is cast to `ChangeSetEntry` by the `foreach` loop, so in both cases you have a variable of type `ChangeSetEntry`.  How you go about getting that variable or populating it isn't relevant in this context.  If the type check is known to fail at compile time for one, it'll be known to fail for the other, unless either the variables are representing different types with the same name, or `RouteStage` means something different in the two contexts.

Comment: @servy you're right. I completely missed that point.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I'm sure the two code blocks are referring to the same type.  One is a modified version of the other.  I haven't changed my using statements at all or modified anything outside this method.

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? It does sound very odd.

Comment: @HighCore: ChangeSetEntries is of type ReadOnlyCollection<ChangeSetEntry>

Comment: OK, it's just me being stupid.  The line should read:

    if (changeRow.Entity is RouteStage)

then it compiles cleanly.  Sorry!  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should read:

```
if (changeRow.Entity is RouteStage)
```

...then it compiles cleanly.  One of those cases of "can't see for looking".  TFS highlighted what I had inadvertently changed.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code examples (exact same conditions you described, in the `Submit` override of a RIA domain service), both are producing a warning.

It's actually expected: in both cases you have `changeRow` that is declared as a `ChangeSetEntry` variable. Whether it's in a `foreach` loop or not doesn't change anything about that. And as `RouteStage` doesn't inherit from `ChangeSetEntry` (which is sealed), the warning should always be displayed.

Either you oversimplified your example (and something is missing), or as Jon Skeet suspected, the `RouteStage` type in both code snippets doesn't actually refer to the same type (check you don't have `using RouteStage = ChangeSetEntry;` somewhere in your class).

Answer (score -1):

> I can understand that, as changeRow is a ChangeSetEntry not a
>   RouteStage, so why does it work inside the foreach block?

I don't think that it *works* in `foreach` loop. The only difference seems to be that compiler doesn't perform static check on variables inside the loop. Hence, no warning displayed. But I suppose that execution never passes `if` within the `foreach` loop because the condition is always false.

Way out of this is just to remove the if statement in both forms, because it is known in advance to never be true.

Comment: The expression does evaluate to 'true' at runtime inside the foreach block.  I ran into the compiler warning when I tried to move the check outside the foreach block.